# What is a recommended workflow using subversion and puppet on centos

Tags: svn, workflow, puppet

this pertains to a scenario where subversion is being used as Version Control , and puppet is used not only to manage packages like tomcat, Jboss, etc, but also applications like perl based application and its CPAN modules, as well as JBoss based web Services, etc along with Mysql and data.

Here is a proposed workflow for a developer's Virtual Machine:

```
Every Virtual Machine ( VMware based)  has : /extra/puppet_dev/modules (maintained under svn)

The complete application runs with the following puppet apply :

sudo puppet apply --modulepath=/extra/puppet_dev/modules/ -e "include company::local"

That will apply the puppet module company, manifests local.pp:

vim /extra/puppet_dev/modules/company/manifests/local.pp, which basically is just calling the company module:

include standards, company

The structure of the whole company application is in its init file:

vim /extra/puppet_dev/modules/company/manifests/init.pp:


class company($instance_name='developer',$cpan_mirror='dite_cpan01'){
 include params, install
 if ( $kernelpageloc =="true" ){  include patches, config, catalyst, catalyst_patch
 }
 include company::index
 include company::jboss

 include webapp_structure, svn_instances, jdk, maven

 class {"apache" : mods => ["rewrite","fastcgi","ssl","jk","ldap","authnz_ldap"], site => "company-ssl-jk",}

 Class['webapp_structure'] -> Class['svn_instances'] -> Class['apache'] -> Class['jdk'] -> Class['company::index'] -> Class['company::jboss'] -> Class['maven']
}


From there we only work on the svn_instances module for svn:

/extra/puppet_dev/modules/svn_instances/manifests/init.pp :

class svn_instances ($instance_name='developer', $instance_level='dev', $build='RC3-1'){

After making your changes just run puppet apply again:


sudo puppet apply --modulepath=/extra/puppet_dev/modules/ -e "include company::local"

Test it and if if you want to apply to all developers virtual machines, just commit changes, you can test general configurations by running:

sudo puppet agent --test
```

what i am looking for is a way to define the boundaries of puppet, and svn, and how they can work together, or should we use something like a subversion module for puppet, and use puppet to drive subversion commands. Keeping in mind that Jenkins is also being used to monitor svn commits, and will kick off builds and tests.

Comment: Question is too vague. What problem do you try to solve?

Comment: Also I'd suggest to shorten or remove text of the example from the question. It hardly helps to understand the problem - too much information.